# can svn server act as pdf storage?

Tags: svn

one customer have the need to store a lot of pdf files, in storage amount they can reach hundreds of giga (total storage). But one pdf file is small in size( may be one or two MO size per pdf)
every pdf can get another version when he is signed. This not a big problem the file can be duplicated when he is signed. the files can be deleted. i will develop a java servlet to store and retrieve files depending on parameters like year,customer_id...
I am hesitating between NFS server or svn server.
svn can have users management, http access, replication active passive in another datacenter.
But NFS also can have these functionality...

Comment: Yes, Subversion server can act as a document storage.

Comment: The number of files or simulataneous access is not a barrier with svn?